# Does vSphere client restrict the number of cores for VMs?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, licensing

We just installed it on our new server and have found that using the vSphere client we cannot create a virtual machine with more than 32 cores (Our host has 64). Is this normal behaviour? We haven't added our licences yet but the trial version we're on should give us full access to all the features correct?

Comment: Just curious, what is the guest OS?

Comment: Oh lordy... Why do people do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

64-way guests are [only supported with Enterprise Plus licenses](http://www.vmware.com/products/datacenter-virtualization/vsphere/compare-editions.html). If you install your Ent+ license, you can configure a VM to have 64 vCPUs (though doing that on a 64 core machine is probably not a wonderful idea).

Comment: Yes, when a VM requiring 64 cores runs, it will not run until all 64 cores in the 64 core machine are available.

Comment: @mdpc actually that CPU scheduling issue was resolved somewhere in the ESXi 3.5 line, but that still doesn't mean that it's a good idea.

Comment: Doesn't running it in the 60 day "evaluation" mode give you access to all features/components?

Comment: All that the [vSphere documents](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.upgrade.doc_50%2FGUID-17862A54-C1D4-47A9-88AA-2A1A32602BC6.html) say about evaluation mode is that you get all of the *features* of vSphere, not that the configuration maximums are at Ent+ levels for the evaluation. Honestly though, if he has Ent+ licenses, he should just install them and unlock the additional vCPU limits and if he doesn't have Ent+ licenses, it doesn't matter a whole lot.

Answer (score 7):

We're missing the version of the vSphere you're using here. That's *very* important.

To answer your question, though, **all** features are enabled during the VMware trial period... (*to get you hooked like **crack***)

I see the 32 vCPU limitation you speak of...

You may need to do this through the **vSphere Web Client** interface and/or update your VM's virtual hardware version from `8` to `vmx-09`...

Example below:

*vSphere client 32 vCPU limit*
[image]

*vSphere web client interface*
[image]

*The option to create up to 64 vCPUs in the vSphere web client*
[image]